# Google Friend Connect - only using Google, not others (e.g. Yahoo or Twitter)

Tags: google-friend-connect

I'm using Google Friend Connect for user authentication.

By default, when you use this, Google lets you use "Google", "Twitter", "Yahoo" and a few others like "AOL" and "OpenID".

Is there an easy way to actually choose which service I want to use? For example, I only want to use Google account for this. What is the best way to filter other services out?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only Google account into your site than you can use OpenID.

[Here](http://www.fryan0911.com/2010/09/use-google-openid-authentication-in.html) is the step-by-step process to implement OpenID on your ASP.NET application using DotNetOpenOAuth libraray (URL: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id – this is the unique OpenID URL of Google Account).

[Tutorial](http://qpleple.com/how-to-make-people-login-into-your-website-with-their-google-account/) describes how to implement Google login( yahoo,etc only just change the URLs, source code is same) in PHP.